# Does there exist a keyword in C# that would make local variables persist across multiple calls?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

That is, in C, we can define a function like:

```
func(){   
  static int foo = 1;   
  foo++;  
  return foo;  
}
```

and it will return a higher number every time it is called. 
Is there an equivalent keyword in C#?

Comment: C was invented when threads didn't exist yet.  So was Visual Basic, they had to implement it in vb.net.  The amount of code it needs to generate to make it thread and exception safe is quite massive.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there's no such thing in C#. All state that you want to persist across multiple method calls has to be in fields, either instance or static.

Except... if you capture the variable in a lambda expression or something like that. For example:

```
public Func<int> GetCounter()
{
    int count = 0;

    return () => count++;
}
```

Now you can use:

```
Func<int> counter = GetCounter();
Console.WriteLine(counter()); // Prints 0
Console.WriteLine(counter()); // Prints 1
Console.WriteLine(counter()); // Prints 2
Console.WriteLine(counter()); // Prints 3
```

Now of course you're only calling `GetCounter()` once, but that "local variable" is certainly living on well beyond the lifetime you might have expected...

That may or may not be any use to you - it depends on what you're doing. But most of the time it really does make sense for an object to have its state in normal fields.

Comment: Does using a closure to simulate a static local variable constitute evil code?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to create a static or instance member variable of the class the method is in.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foo
{
    static int _bar = 1;

    public int Bar()
    {
        return ++_bar;
    }
}
```